# Does row level security works if null value found in cube model

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I have created one sales cube which has country wise sales table and country table and security group table like below.

SALES TABLE:

```
    country     sales_amount    
     India             50000          
      UK               50000          
     NULL              50000
```

COUNTRY NAME:

```
    country  security_group_id
     India       S1
      UK         S2
```

SECURITY TABLE:

```
  User_name  security_group_id
    ABC               S1
    XYZ               S2
```

I am trying to restrict the data country wise,Here I got some issue what if country column has null value and how to handle row level security.

Here,Two users are unable to access data which has gl_country NULL.

How to handle in such that cases.

Comment: I have created relationship between sales[country]---->country_name[country] and country_name[security_group_id]---->security_table[security_group_id],but ABC user unable to access information with NULL GL_COUNTRY_ID

Answer (score 0):

The NULL value of the country column in table `SALES` won't affect the execution of row level security. 
Row level security  restrict data based on which windows user loggs in and in our case the related condition columns are `User_name` and `security_group_id`.

For more details about `Row level security`, please refer:

[Dynamic row level security with Analysis services tabular model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tutorial-row-level-security-onprem-ssas-tabular)